# how to replace the content data of a found file whose name it keeps?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for a solution to replace the CONTENT data of the file whose name must be kept

because, I would like the URL of the image, placed in the HTML, to remain fixed and never change. But, In this url, the image changes .

For example, the default advertising image is displayed forever. When January 1st, we change the "Happy New Year" image for 3 weeks, and then beyond the 4th week, we resume the default advertising image.

here is part of my procedure below, to replace the image content.
using "setcontent", it doesn'work...
How to replace the content in the file "test_pub.png" ,

```js
function chercherimage()
{
 Logger.log('Debut chercherimage() ');      

  //** aller chercher l'image publicitaire 

    var FilePub_id ="1cqGT3TV5M_RMqXj6MSD8LEjNaip2Iyio";
    
    var folder_name ="pub";
    
    // Get folder by id
     var folderIter = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder_name);
     
     var Dossier = folderIter.next();
     var Id_Dossier = Dossier.getId()
     Logger.log('Dossier  :'+Dossier.getName() );
     
     var filesIter  = Dossier.getFiles();
     
     var i = 0;
     var flag ="N";   
     while(filesIter.hasNext())
     {
     i++;
     var file = filesIter.next();
     var file_id = file.getId();
      var filename = file .getName();
   
     if (filename =="INE_marche_national_toulouse.png")
     {
          if ( FilePub_id == file_id )
          {
             var flag ="O"; 
             Logger.log('file_id trouvé  :'+file_id );
            
             var filesize = file .getSize();
             var data = Utilities.base64Encode(file.getBlob().getBytes());
             var Mime_Type=file.getMimeType();
            Logger.log('filename  :'+filename);
            Logger.log('filesize   :'+filesize );
            Logger.log('data   :'+data );
            Logger.log('Mime_Type   :'+Mime_Type );
            
            var parm_info =[folder_name,Id_Dossier, file_id, filename, filesize , file , data, Mime_Type  ];
            
           // lancer pour remplacer le contenu de l'image dans le drive pub partage
           remplace_file(parm_info);
           break;
           }
        }
     }
 Logger.log('Fin chercherimage() ');    
}

    function remplace_file(parm_info)
    {
    // ces variables trouvées
    var folder_name_source = parm_info[0];
    var Id_Dossier_source = parm_info[1];
    var file_id_source = parm_info[2];
    var filename_source = parm_info[3];
    var filesize_source = parm_info[4];  
    var file_source  =parm_info[5];
    var data_source  =parm_info[6];
    var Mime_Type_source = parm_info[7];  

    // preparation pour remplacer le contenu de ces variables dans le lien partagé
    // aller chercher le dossier partagé : image_partagé

      var folder_name ="pubpartage";
      var folderIter = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder_name);
         
      var Dossier_partage = folderIter.next();
      var Id_Dossier = Dossier_partage .getId()
      Logger.log('Dossier_partage   :'+Dossier_partage .getName() );
         
     var filesIter  =Dossier_partage.getFiles();
     var i=0;
          while(filesIter.hasNext())
         {
         i++;
         var file = filesIter.next();
         var file_name = file.getName();
         var file_id = file.getId();

         Logger.log('file_id partage :'+file_id );
         Logger.log('file_name partage :'+file_name );
         
          // à remplacer les contenus des données ...   
         if (file_name =="test_pub.png")
         {
 // ==> error how to do to correct it, see below  :       
  // file.setcontent(data_source );
         break;
         }

        }
    }
```

---

Following my test, it does not work because of an error message: file id not found!!! ...
I do not understand why this error however, I examined the point of error to capture the n°file during the reading in loop!!! .
How should I do to target the exact file number?

of course, I put "   var data = file.getBlob();" in an other function "chercherimage()".

see a function " remplace_file(parm_info)" below for

```js
function remplace_file(parm_info)
{
// ces variables trouvées
var folder_name_source = parm_info[0];
var Id_Dossier_source = parm_info[1];
var file_id_source = parm_info[2];
var filename_source = parm_info[3];
var filesize_source = parm_info[4];  
var file_source  =parm_info[5];
var data_source  =parm_info[6];
var Mime_Type_source = parm_info[7];  

// preparation pour remplacer le contenu de ces variables dans le lien partagé
// aller chercher le dossier partagé : image_partagé

  var folder_name ="pubpartage";
  var folderIter = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder_name);
     
  var Dossier_partage = folderIter.next();
  var Id_Dossier = Dossier_partage .getId()
  Logger.log('Dossier_partage   :'+Dossier_partage .getName() );
     
 var filesIter  =Dossier_partage.getFiles();
 var i=0;
      while(filesIter.hasNext())
     {
     i++;
     var file = filesIter.next();
     var file_name = file.getName();
     var file_id = file.getId();

     var mimeType = file.getMimeType(); 
     Logger.log('file_id partage :'+file_id );
     Logger.log('file_name partage :'+file_name );
     Logger.log('mimeType  partage :'+mimeType  );
     
      // à remplacer les contenus des données ...   
     if (file_name =="test_pub.png")
     {
       var file_resource = {
        title: file_name,
        mimeType: mimeType 
  };
      
  Drive.Files.update(file_resource, file_id, data_source);
    break;
     }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want the shared drive, then `supportsAllDrives:true` is needed. See Octavia Sima's updated answer.

Comment: Also, stop posting updates as answer. Modify your post to clarify it instead of posting unnecessary answers

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

- Upon testing, the error is `TypeError: file.setcontent is not a function`. It should be `file.setContent`

[image: error]

#### Solution:

- I'd recommend you use Drive API services instead to update the file. Enable it first then have these modifications:

#### Modification 1:

- Have `data` contain the blob, since `Drive.files.update` later on will need blob type data.

```
var data = file.getBlob();
```

#### Modification 2:

- Use `Drive.files.update`

```
if (file_name == "test_pub.png") {
  var file_resource = {
    title: file_name,
    mimeType: Mime_Type_source
  };
      
  Drive.Files.update(file_resource, file_id, data_source);
  break;
}
```

#### pub:

[image: original]

#### pubpartage:

[image: output]

#### EDIT:

- If you want to update a file in a shared drive, then try this additional modifications:

#### Modification 3:

- Specify the folder using its ID instead. `DriveApp.getFoldersByName` will only search for your own drive.

```
// shared folder ID
var Id_Dossier = '0AGwRX5g4Y1d8Uk9PVA';
var Dossier_partage = DriveApp.getFolderById(Id_Dossier);
```

#### Modification 4:

- Add additional data in your resource, and `supportsAllDrives:true` must be added to the `Drive.Files.update`.

```
var file_resource = {
  title: file_name,
  mimeType: Mime_Type_source,
  driveId: Id_Dossier,
  parents: Id_Dossier
};

Drive.Files.update(file_resource, file_id, data_source, {supportsAllDrives:true});
```

#### Script:

```
function chercherimage() {
  Logger.log('Debut chercherimage() ');
  //** aller chercher l'image publicitaire 

  var FilePub_id = "<original file id>";
  var folder_name = "pub";

  // Get folder by id
  var folderIter = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder_name);

  var Dossier = folderIter.next();
  var Id_Dossier = Dossier.getId()
  Logger.log('Dossier  :' + Dossier.getName());

  var filesIter = Dossier.getFiles();

  var i = 0;
  var flag = "N";
  while (filesIter.hasNext()) {
    i++;
    var file = filesIter.next();
    var file_id = file.getId();
    var filename = file.getName();

    if (filename == "INE_marche_national_toulouse.png") {
      if (FilePub_id == file_id) {
        var flag = "O";
        Logger.log('file_id trouvé  :' + file_id);

        var filesize = file.getSize();
        var data = file.getBlob();
        var Mime_Type = file.getMimeType();
        Logger.log('filename  :' + filename);
        Logger.log('filesize   :' + filesize);
        Logger.log('data   :' + data);
        Logger.log('Mime_Type   :' + Mime_Type);

        var parm_info = [folder_name, Id_Dossier, file_id, filename, filesize, file, data, Mime_Type];

        // lancer pour remplacer le contenu de l'image dans le drive pub partage
        remplace_file(parm_info);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log('Fin chercherimage() ');
}

function remplace_file(parm_info) {
  // ces variables trouvées
  var folder_name_source = parm_info[0];
  var Id_Dossier_source = parm_info[1];
  var file_id_source = parm_info[2];
  var filename_source = parm_info[3];
  var filesize_source = parm_info[4];
  var file_source = parm_info[5];
  var data_source = parm_info[6];
  var Mime_Type_source = parm_info[7];

  // preparation pour remplacer le contenu de ces variables dans le lien partagé
  // aller chercher le dossier partagé : image_partagé
  // shared folder ID
  var Id_Dossier = '<shared folder id>';
  var Dossier_partage = DriveApp.getFolderById(Id_Dossier);

  var filesIter = Dossier_partage.getFiles();
  var i = 0;
  while (filesIter.hasNext()) {
    i++;
    var file = filesIter.next();
    var file_name = file.getName();
    var file_id = file.getId();

    Logger.log('file_id partage :' + file_id);
    Logger.log('file_name partage :' + file_name);

    // à remplacer les contenus des données ...   
    if (file_name == "test_pub.png") {
      var file_resource = {
        title: file_name,
        mimeType: Mime_Type_source,
        driveId: Id_Dossier,
        parents: Id_Dossier
      };
      
      Drive.Files.update(file_resource, file_id, data_source, {supportsAllDrives:true});
      break;
    }

  }
}
```

#### Sample:

[image: sample]

#### Output:

[image: output]